# Триггер на удаление

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, триггер

Есть триггер который срабатывает когда удаляется 1 запись из таблицы и меняется данные в другой таблице.

Как изменить код чтобы можно было удалять сразу несколько записей?
Удаляется одна запись из таблицы Books_Readers, то по id книги должно инкрементировать Count соответствующей записи в таблице Books. 
Например: в библиотеку возвращают книги несколько читателей, которые написал 1 автор.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Books_up
     ON [Books_Readers]
     FOR DELETE 
     AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idBook numeric(11, 0)
    DECLARE @count int;
    SET @idBook = ( SELECT d.Book_Kod
                    FROM inserted i
                    FULL OUTER JOIN deleted d ON i.Book_Kod = d.Book_Kod)
    SET @count = (SELECT Count FROM Books WHERE Books.kod = @idBook)
    update Books SET Count = (Count+1) WHERE kod = @idBook;
    Print @idBook
END
GO
```

[image: Структура таблиц]

Даний код не будет работать если я выполню запрос:

```
insert INTO Books_Readers(Book_Kod,Reader_Kod,OnHand)VALUES (4,1,'2012-08-08')
insert INTO Books_Readers(Book_Kod,Reader_Kod,OnHand)VALUES (4,2,'2012-08-08')
```

А когда выполню этот код то будет ошибка

```
delete Books_Readers WHERE Book_Kod = 4
```

> Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения. Это запрещено, когда
>   вложенный запрос следует после =, !=, <, <=, >, >= или используется в
>   качестве выражения.

Comment: Приведите схему ваших таблиц. И данные заполнения. Иначе непонятно, что должно обновляться при удалении чего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас должно быть что-то наподобие:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Books_up ON [Books_Readers]
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on;

    with d
    as (
        select Book_Kod, [Count] = count(1)
        from deleted
        group by Book_Kod
    )
    update b
    set b.[Count] = b.[Count] + d.[Count]
    from Books b
        join d on d.Book_Kod = b.kod

END
GO
```

Т.е. группируете кол-во книг в `deleted` по коду и этот результат соединяете с таблицей `Books`, обновляя в ней количества.

Comment: вы все правильно поняли) Спасибо большое. Правда код для меня немного не понятен. Но это я уже как то сам)